# How to add speed limit sign on Apple CarPlay?

Tags: swift, navigation, carplay

I want to add a speed limit sign to my navigation app when I'm using it on my CarPlay.
But as Apple writes in their documentation, it is forbidden to create custom overlays over their mapTemplates. The only thing I am allowed to draw is the map.

But I can see Google Maps have a speed limit on CarPlay. I am wondering how they could add it without creating a custom overlay.

Apple documentation says I need to use their and only their template to display the interface, but they have no "box" so to say on the right top corner, on `CPMapTemplate`, to showcase a speed limit sign.

Has anyone here tried something similar for their navigation app?

I did get it to work by creating a custom overlay on my root view controller, but is only supposed to show the templates.

Comment: I feel that I have read the same topic some 24 hours ago.